# Updating a Control's location after the Windows Form's max size has been reached

Tags: c#, winforms, location, vsto, autosize

I have a Windows Form where I can dynamically add/remove Controls (in rows).

Everything works as intended, until the Windows Form's max size has been reached.

After that happens the Control's locations won't update correctly anymore.

Here's an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUtSx.png

It might be useful to know that the Windows Form has `AutoSize = true` and `AutoSizeMode = GorwAndShrink`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, found the answer on a 9 year old discussion: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/270543/control-added-on-the-fly-is-added-to-the-wrong-location-of-an-auto-scroll-panel

**TL;DR** Setting a Control's location when the Control is invisible doesn't work correctly. Making the Controls visible before I set their locations fixed all my problems.